# Como escrever horários nas entradas do console sem repetir muito código

Tags: c#, .net

Queria que toda `Console.WriteLine` seja desse jeito quando for mandada para o Console:

> [10:38:12:758]- Mensagem digitada no WriteLine

Bom já fiz uma parte que é esta:

```
private static DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"));
```

Porém, quero escrever várias mensagens, e no caso eu teria que ficar digitando esse código um monte de vezes, queria que fosse algo tipo assim:

"CW("Mensagem")" e já aparecesse o "DateTime now" no formato que eu citei acima, como posso fazer isto?

Fiz este código:

```
public void msg(string mensagem)
{
    mensagem = "";
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}], [{1}]", data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), mensagem);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    msg("Teste");
}
```

Porém, não aparece a mensagem "Teste"

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar todo o código?

Comment: Editei e coloquei o código

Comment: Este código não faz sentido.

Comment: Sim, coloquei uma coisa q não fez sentido ali haha

Comment: Você está deixando a variável teste sem texto ali `mensagem = "";`

Comment: Você que escrever uma mensagem e adicionar a data junto? só não quer ficar digitando a data em todas as mensagem ?

Comment: Já consegui amigo obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crie seu próprio método que recebe um texto como entrada ;)

```
public void EscreverNoConsole(string texto) {
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]-{1}", data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), texto);
}
```

Daí, sempre que quiser escrever no console, ao invés de chamar Console.WriteLine, chame o método que você criou.

```
EscreverNoConsole("Quero vê-la sorrir, quero vê-la cantar");
EscreverNoConsole("Quero ver o seu corpo dançar sem parar");
```

A isso chamamos de encapsulamento. Tudo que você precisa repetir bastante, você pode encapsular em uma função ou método.

Comment: +1 pelo Sidney Magal

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim (cada linha em um lugar bem diferente, não é um código sequencial):

```
using static System.Console;

private static DateTime data = DateTime.Now;

WriteLine($"[{data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")}]");
```

Eu não faria, mas se quiser fazer gambiarra mesmo:

```
public static void WL(string format, params args) => WriteLine(format, string[] args);
```

De acordo com a edição eu faria assim:

```
public void CW(string mensagem) => WriteLine($"[{data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")}]-{mensagem}");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/Abstraction.cs).

Difícil ser "simplificar" mais que isto.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um método que receba como parâmetro a mensagem que você deseja imprimir:

```
public void ExibirMensagem(string msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), msg);
}
```

Assim você chama o método passando o texto que deve ser mostrado e será exibida na formatação especificada.

**exemplo**:

```
if (1)
    ExibirMensagem("Mensagem número UM");
else if (2)
    ExibirMensagem("Mensagem número DOIS");
else
    ExibirMensagem("Mensagem número TRÊS");
```

**retorno**:

> ```
> [10:47:12:756]- Mensagem número UM
> [10:47:12:757]- Mensagem número DOIS
> [10:47:12:758]- Mensagem número TRÊS
> ```

Comment: Obrigado, só errei em uma coisinha simples kkkk

Comment: Este código nem compila

Comment: Vlw, @Maniero.. corrigido