# DateTime não atualiza no Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando clico no botão, algo é escrito no Console junto com a data, porém a hora não atualiza.

Código:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"));
    }
```

Console:
11:37:55:540
11:37:55:540
11:37:55:540
11:37:55:540

Comment: E não vai atualizar mesmo, você terá que construir todo um algoritmo que faça isto, não é algo simples e está longe do desejado. A primeira coisa que precisava saber agora já sabe, computadores não são mágicos, você coloca algo e ele faz o que quer. Você tem que construir o que precisa. De qualquer forma já é algo muito estranho misturar WinForms com console.

Comment: Eu pensava que ia atualizar todo "milisegundos" , porque tipo, ele não está mandando 5 mensagens ao mesmo tempo para ter o mesmo datetime. E precisava de uma base desse algoritimo que você citou, pois não faço a miníma ideia de como começar

Comment: O problema é este, você quer fazer o teto, o acabamento, sem fazer o alicerce, assentar o tijolo.

Comment: Diego, porque editou a pergunta? Agora as respostas ficaram sem sentido.

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois ela invalida as respostas dadas. Se tem outra dúvida, abra pergunta em separado. Leitura recomendada para melhor aproveitamento do site: [Tour], [Ask] e [Help].

Comment: Console com winforms? Que lambança é essa?

Answer (score 2):

O DateTime não é um "relógio" que altera a sua representação com o passar do tempo.

DateTime é imutável, ele representa o instante em que foi criado.

Para fazer o que prentende tem de criar um objecto DateTime sempre que queira apresentar o instante actual:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"));
}
```

Comment: Pela pergunta e comentários não parece que seja isso, ele quer que fique atualizando o horário sozinho automaticamente, o que torna a pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: Parece que era, veja a resposta [dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240101/2541). Apesar que aquilo que você está pensando também fosse uma possibilidade

Comment: Eu tentei o seu mas não atualizou, só consegui com a minha resposta, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: Então está tudo inconsistente, termo errado, comentários errados, a resposta dele não faz o menor sentido, na verdade, eu acho que ele só quer me contrariar. Nota-se agora como nada faz sentido. pra falar a verdade o certo é fechar como não clara de tanta confusão que tem nessa pergunta. Se eu fizesse com interpolação que eu gosto mais ele diria que não deu certo também.

Comment: @Maniero É, não há razão para ele dizer que o meu código não funciona.

Comment: @ramaral sim, funciona, não como o descrito, mas o seu funciona. Eu acho até o que o dele fazia mais sentido porque ele não quer o `Now`(pelo menos parece, como muita coisa na pergunta, resposta e comentários dele não faz sentido, vai saber), ele quer uma data da classe. E quer que ela vá atualizando. Deixa pra lá, esses casos são tão confusos que nem vale a pena perder tempo. Por mim fecharia a pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero, eu interpretei como que ele quisesse o instante quando clicasse no botão(`Console.WriteLine()` no evento do botão), no entanto a sua interpretação também é válida. Eu até votava para fechar, mas após a resposta dele não sei se deva.

Comment: A resposta dele me fez querer fechar ;) Ficou calro que nada aqui faz sentido. A resposta dele não resolveu nada, ele criou uma variável com um valor, mudou seu valor em seguida e depois a ignorou, e continuou o código como o da pergunta, ou seja, não tem como isto ter resolvido alguma coisa. Fui ver as perguntas anteriores e é só lambança.

Comment: @ramaral https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239676/101 a solução já estava dada. Veja o padrão de perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239738/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239650/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239366/101. Não vou entrar em detalhes, mas vc é esperto acho que vai entender o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não intendi muito bem sua pergunta. Mas pelo que intendi você precisa atualizar a hora cada vez que clicar no botão. Então, tá aí o código

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var date = DateTime.Now;//Se esta variável já estiver criada, remova o 'var'
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", data.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"));
}
```

E se for para atualizar o horário sozinho, usa um `timer` ja que está usando WinForms também.

Comment: Pela pergunta e comentários não parece que seja isso, ele quer que fique atualizando o horário sozinho automaticamente, o que torna a pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: @Maneiro Pode ser, mas não faz sentido atualizar a hora automaticamente já que só é escrita quando o botão é clicado

Comment: Mas foi o que ele disse nos comentários. O clique provavelmente seria só para iniciar isto. Na verdade nem vou mexer com isso mais, a pergunta está bem confusa, ele não sabe o que quer, o que funciona. Fica só os comentários para quem chegar aqui e ver que nada disso faz sentido. Desde o início eu vi que o `Now`não era a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Agora está atualizando..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"));
            }
```